# Not able to install RWeka

Tags: r, rweka

I am facing issues while installing the RWeka package. I tried installing rJava but even that is not being installed, can someone help here with the issue? You can follow the code for the error message

```
> install.packages("RWeka")

WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/1911120/Documents/R/win-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
      binary source needs_compilation
RWeka 0.4-42 0.4-43             FALSE

installing the source package ‘RWeka’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/RWeka_0.4-43.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 451318 bytes (440 KB)
downloaded 440 KB

* installing *source* package 'RWeka' ...
** package 'RWeka' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation

   **********************************************
   WARNING: this package has a configure script
         It probably needs manual configuration
   **********************************************


** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error: .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: fun(libname, pkgname)
  error: JAVA_HOME cannot be determined from the Registry
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'RWeka'
* removing 'C:/Users/1911120/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/RWeka'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘RWeka’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: What architecture are you on?  Apple?

Comment: The error is very verbal about your problem. **WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:** It even provides a link. Also I'd suggest updating R to 4.0.2, before installing Rtools.

Comment: Hi Oliver, I already tried downloading RTools, it was still showing the same error

Comment: @G5W Not apple, windows